# Trying to figure out NameError: in Python program

Tags: python

Trying to figure out NameError: in python program. The program is supposed to give a user three choices for different types of carpet then prompts them for the height and width. Based on the price of the carpet and what they input for their height and width it should print out the total cost for them. I am getting a NameError saying carpetgrade is not defined. Could anyone check it out and explain why it isnt?

```
def full_cost(height, width, carpetgrade):

    cost = carpetgrade * area

    area = height * width

    return cost
        
polyester = 45

wool = 75

acrylic = 100

print("Choose a grade of carpet. There is polyester, wool, and acryilic")

carpet_selection = (input("Which carpet grade do you choose?"))

if (carpet_selection == polyester):
    carpetgrade = 45
                       
elif (carpet_selection == wool):
    carpetgrade = 75
    
elif (carpet_selection == acrylic):
    carpetgrade = 100

height = int(input("What is the height of the room?"))

width = int(input("What is the width of the room?"))

complete_cost = full_cost(height, width, carpetgrade)

print("The cost of your carpet is ,complete_cost")
```

Here is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdXAc.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Assignment 3.py", line 34, in <module>
    complete_cost = full_cost(height, width, carpetgrade)
NameError: name 'carpetgrade' is not defined
```

Comment: Please edit your post to fix your code formatting. You should copy and paste the entire section of code as a single block, then re-select the entire block of code and click the `{}` button. I cannot do this for you because I do not want to make assumptions about how your actual code is indented, and indentation matters in Python.

Comment: But: In your own words, when you try to call the function like `full_cost(height, width, carpetgrade)`, how are you expecting it to know what value it should use for `carpetgrade`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` statements, you are checking if the input `carpet_selection` is equal to `polyester`, `wool`, or `acrylic`. But, I'm assuming you want to check if the user is inputting these actual words (from your image - you entered the word "wool".) You'll need to put these in quotes, because right now, your code is looking to see if the user input is equal to your previously defined *variables*, which have names `polyester`, `wool`, and `acrylic`. To check for the input being equal to a *string*, you need to put these words in quotes, since that's the syntax for Python strings.

Since the input will always initially be a string, and your code is checking to see if the input is equal to those variables (which are of type `int`), none of the conditions will ever evaluate to be true, and thus, `carpetgrade` will never be defined. So, your if statements should look something like this:

```
if (carpet_selection == "polyester"): carpetgrade = 45

elif (carpet_selection == "wool"): carpetgrade = 75

elif (carpet_selection == "acrylic"): carpetgrade = 100
```

Now, there is one more caveat - in the function `full_cost`, you are doing arithmetic with the variable `carpetgrade`. So, before you pass the variable into the function, you'll need to do something to convert `carpetgrade` into a value that you can work with in arithmetic/mathematical operations - you could try setting up some more if conditions to check for what `carpetgrade` could be equal to, and then set it to the integer/numerical value that you want.

Comment: You should also consider what happens if the user types something else.